# find the biggest difference between numbers

Tags: php, random

i have 7 numbers in random from -100 to 100, from those seven numbers i need to find the biggest diference between each them

example:

```
-50 , 60 , -4 , 80 , 25, -34, 15
```

the output will be 130 -50 and 80 is the biggest diference

but i need in php

i have tried `echo max(rand(-100, 100));`

but it is not the output im looking for

this i tried too:

```
$myarray = array(
  'this' => 2, 
  'that' => 14, 
  'them' => -5, 
  'other' => 200, 
  'nothing' => 42, 
  'somethingelse' => 1, 
  'you' => 10, 
  'me' => 30);

foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
  if (!isset ($min) || $value < $min) { $min = $value; }
  if (!isset ($max) || $value > $max) { $max = $value; }
}

$diff = $max - $min;
echo $diff;
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$array = array(-50 , 60 , -4 , 80 , 25, -34, 15);

$min = 0;
$max = 0;

foreach($array as $element) {
        if ($element < $min) $min = $element;
        if ($element > $max) $max = $element;
}

echo $max - $min;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach using `max()` wasn’t wrong, but `max()` expects an array as its first parameter whereas `rand()` only returns a single integer.

The solution should be:

```
$diff = max($myarray) - min($myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$myarray = array(
  'this' => 2, 
  'that' => 14, 
  'them' => -5, 
  'other' => 200, 
  'nothing' => 42, 
  'somethingelse' => 1, 
  'you' => 10, 
  'me' => 30);

function bigDiff($arr){
    if(count($arr)>0){
        $max = max($arr);
        $min = min($arr);
        $diff =  ($max)-($min);

        return $diff;
    }
    return "Null input array provided";
}
echo bigDiff($myarray);
```

outputs 205

Answer (score 0):

This could be another way:

```
$arr = array(
   'this' => 2,
   'that' => 14,
   'them' => -5,
   'other' => 200,
   'nothing' => 42,
   'somethingelse' => 1,
   'you' => 10,
   'me' => 30
);
sort($arr);
$diff = $arr[count($arr) - 1] - $arr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$array = array(-50 , 60 , -4 , 80 , 25, -34, 15);

$max = max($array);  //80
$min = min($array);  //-50
$difference = $max - $min;  //130
```